# Pardot Authentication error

Tags: api, pardot

I am authenticating the Pardot org from the Pardot API console and getting an error:

```
<rsp stat="fail" version="1.0">
    <err code="15">Login failed</err>
</rsp>
```

How to resolve this error when the my request is:

```
email=<test.user@pardot.com>&password=<test@123>&user_key=<sdsdgkflg32324334gn2323d23f23gh34g3435d35556f77g8dgjk>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was putting in my request directly into the text body and generating the body through the parameters provided in the console.